# Facing issue to create Build and Release Pipeline using Azure DevOps Classic Pipeline for .pfx certificate importing to VM Servers

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, release

Step 1: Added pfx file as secure file in the Azure DevOps Library

Not sure how to proceed with Build & release classic pipeline to import certificate in VM Servers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvsGl.png)

Step 2: Created a Build pipeline using Download Secure file & using powershell script using thumbprint function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpeOI.png)

used variable group to store the Certificate password

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orKk6.png)

Result - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nweCY.png) - not sure if the build is created properly.

Not sure how to proceed with Build and Release Pipeline using the classic build pipeline to get the pfx file imported in one VM server and installed in all VM servers in that domain.